# Google Apps Engine reading URL Query (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, get

Can someone please provide an example of how to read and print "sydney" and "NSW" from URL:

```
http://xyz.appspot.com/main?city=sydney&state=NSW
```

Using the `def get (name, city, state)` function?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its quite simple use

```
def get(self):
  city = self.request.get('city')
  state = self.request.get('state')
```

This is one the first things you get from

> [Getting started with Google AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/handlingforms.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using webapp2 under Python 2.7

check out 
http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html

Comment: Link is now dead.